# behavior of nested scope definitions in web/router.ex

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

The docs do not mention this at all. Is it allowed to nest scope definitions, and if so what is the defined behaviour for the following in web/router.ex:

```
scope "/:locale", MyApp do
  pipe_through [:browser, :locale]

  scope "/auth", MyApp do
    pipe_through [:auth]

    get "/", PageController, :dummy
  end

  get "/", PageController, :dummy
end
```

Do pipes chain, .i.e are the /:locale/auth requests route through :browser, :locale AND :auth? Any gotchas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is allowed to scope definitions, and pipelines are inherited by nested scopes. The Phoenix repo [contains tests for pipelines in nested scopes](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/24c0d68ec14bd6c186e92b8191ae9fb9c6ef5a11/test/phoenix/router/pipeline_test.exs) which assert that all the `pipe_through` in the parent scopes are inherited by the routes in the child scopes.

```
scope "/browser" do
  pipe_through :browser
  get "/root", SampleController, :index

  scope "/api" do
    pipe_through :api
    get "/root", SampleController, :index
  end
end

# ...

test "invokes pipelines in a nested scope" do
  conn = call(Router, :get, "/browser/api/root")
  assert conn.private[:phoenix_pipelines] == [:browser, :api]
  assert conn.assigns[:stack] == "api"
end
```

Answer (score 4):

You will have the following routes

```
# The following route has the :browser and :locale plugs
/:locale/      # Points to MyApp.PageController.dummy

# The following route has the :browser, :locale and :auth plugs
/:locale/auth/ # Points to MyApp.MyApp.PageController.dummy
```

I feel like you do not want to actually point to `MyApp.MyApp.PageController`, so you can define a [`scope/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Router.html#scope/2) without specifying the alias.

```
scope "/:locale", MyApp do
  pipe_through [:browser, :locale]

  scope "/auth" do
    pipe_through [:auth]

    get "/", PageController, :dummy
  end
end
```

This will now just point your auth route to `MyApp.PageController`.